# Flex 4 layout similar to match the following layout( wired connection like layout)

Tags: apache-flex, layout, drag-and-drop

I need to develop a flex application which is similar to match the following layout. 
From the list I need to drag and drop items into a panel. I need to visualize wired connections between the items in the panel.
Moreover if i click one item in the panel, the rest all the items should glow with a plus sign indicating connections can be made. Once connection has been made it has to show negative sign.
 [image: Match the following layout]
Any help on doing this.

Comment: You are missing an image here.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to directly solve this problem but i a have solution which gives the same result wanted by you

here it is the code:

```
<s:GridItemRenderer currentState="normal" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function state1_enterStateHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
            bc.setStyle("backgroundColor",0xff0018);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State enterState="state1_enterStateHandler(event)" name="myState"/>
    <s:State name="selected"/>
</s:states>

<s:BorderContainer id="bc" left="0" right="0" height="{this.height}"/>
<s:Button click="this.currentState = 'prova'"/>
```